# Form multiplication

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need these two fields to be multiplied together based on selected form options.

Okay so it works without all the extra fields but once i added the rest of the form the calculation stopped working. :(

```
          <form action="mailer.php" data-validate="parsley" method="post" >
          <p><strong>Full Name<span class="red">*</span></strong></p>
          <input name="cf_name" data-required="true"  class="send" type="text" />
          <p><strong>Email Address<span class="red">*</span></strong></p>
          <input name="cf_email" data-required="true" data-type="email" class="send" type="text" />
          <p><strong>Cellphone No.<span class="red">*</span></strong></p>
          <input name="cf_cell" data-required="true" class="send" type="text" />

          <p><strong>Instrument Type<span class="red">*</span></strong></p>
          <select name="cf_instrument" size="1" class="option" >
          <option value="Piano">Piano</option>
          <option value="Vocals">Vocals</option>
          <option value="Guitar">Guitar</option>
          <option value="Bass">Bass</option>
          <option value="Flute">Flute</option></select>

          <p><strong>Lesson Type<span class="red">*</span></strong></p>
          <select name="cf_package_type" id="cf_package_type" size="1" class="option">
          <option value="100">Beginner Lesson - R100</option>
          <option value="130">Advanced Lesson - R130</option>
          <option value="160">Professional Lesson - R160</option></select>

          <p><strong>No. of Lessons<span class="red">*</span></strong></p>
          <select id="number-of-lessons" name="cf_number" size="1" class="option" onchange='test()'>
          <option name="1" value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
          <option name="2" value="2">2</option>
          <option name="3" value="3">3</option>
          <option name="4" value="4">4</option></select>

          <script src="js/datepair.js"></script>
             <p><strong>Lesson Date & Time<span class="red">*</span></strong></p>
                <p class="datepair" data-language="javascript">
          <input type="text" name="cf_booking_date" class="date start" data-required="true" />
          <input type="text" name="cf_start_time" class="time start" data-required="true" /> to
          <input type="text" name="cf_end_time" class="time end" data-required="true" /></p>

          <script src="js/datepair.js"></script>
                <p id="lesson-2" class="datepair" data-language="javascript">
          <input type="text" name="cf_booking_date" class="date start" data-required="true"  />
          <input type="text" name="cf_start_time" class="time start" data-required="true"  /> to
          <input type="text" name="cf_end_time" class="time end" data-required="true"  /></p>

          <script src="js/datepair.js"></script>
                <p id="lesson-3" class="datepair" data-language="javascript">
          <input type="text" name="cf_booking_date" class="date start" data-required="true"  />
          <input type="text" name="cf_start_time" class="time start" data-required="true"  /> to
          <input type="text" name="cf_end_time" class="time end" data-required="true"  /></p>

          <script src="js/datepair.js"></script>
                <p id="lesson-4" class="datepair" data-language="javascript">
          <input type="text" name="cf_booking_date" class="date start" data-required="true"  />
          <input type="text" name="cf_start_time" class="time start" data-required="true"  /> to
          <input type="text" name="cf_end_time" class="time end" data-required="true"  /></p> 

           <!-- HIDDEN FIELD - HONEYPOT ANTI_SPAM -->
          <input id="website" class="using" name="website" type="text"  />
          <!-- END -->
          <input name="Submit" class="submit" value="Book Now" type="submit" /></form>  

          <input type="text" value="100" disabled="disabled" id="result">
```

Corrected JS used:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("select").change(function(){
      var val1 = + ($("#cf_package_type").val());
      var val2 = + ($("#number-of-lessons").val());
      $("#result").val(val1*val2);
});

</script>
```

I know i'm probably very off-track but if someone could please help me with this it would be a life-saver!

Here's the JS fiddle to help you - http://jsfiddle.net/GuBPL/10/

Thank you.

Comment: too many syntax errors. check this: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/GuBPL/2/

Comment: @abhitalks I've fixed it in my answer ;-)

Comment: Also is there anyway to echo the amount to another page upon submit? I've sorted out the php post form and it is set to re-direct to a "sent" page. Is there a way to echo the amount on this sent page?

Comment: correct too many syntax errors. I have [slighly modified](http://jsfiddle.net/sivatumma/GuBPL/5/) to correct it. Used `class` along with the `name` attribute with the same values. `keyup` was used where it should have been A `change` event I think.

Comment: @hsz: :) yes of course. i took a few seconds to post that comment.. slow connection... didn't notice your answer! +1 to yr answer.

Comment: Hey guys! If you read through the original post again you'll notice i added the rest of the HTML form but now the calculation doesn't seem to be working??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with following code:

```
<p><strong>Lesson Type<span class="red">*</span></strong></p>
<select id="cf_package_type" name="cf_package_type" size="1" class="option">
    <option value="100">Beginner Lesson - R100</option>
    <option value="130">Advanced Lesson - R130</option>
    <option value="160">Professional Lesson - R160</option>
</select>

<p><strong>No. of Lessons<span class="red">*</span></strong></p>
<select id="number-of-lessons" name="cf_number" size="1" class="option">
    <option value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
    <option name="2" value="2">2</option>
    <option name="3" value="3">3</option>
    <option name="4" value="4">4</option>
</select>

<input type="text" disabled="disabled" id="result">
```

And JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#number-of-lessons").change(function(){
          var val1 = parseInt($("#cf_package_type").val());
          var val2 = parseInt($(this).val());
          $("#result").val(val1*val2);
    });
});
```

**What's changed ?**

First select got `id="cf_package_type"` attribute, which is used to get its value with:

```
$("#cf_package_type").val()
```

Removed `onchange='test()'` because we do it with `jQuery`:

```
$("#number-of-lessons").change()
```

Get value of second select with:

```
$(this).val()
```

because we work on it already.

`parseInt` used just to be sure, we use integers, not strings.

**Edit:**

To calculate result on page load, use:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var calculate = function(){
          var val1 = parseInt($("#cf_package_type").val());
          var val2 = parseInt($('#number-of-lessons').val());
          $("#result").val(val1*val2);
    };
    $("#number-of-lessons").change(calculate);
    calculate();
});
```

Comment: i think only js is enough - you can delete the html part.

Comment: @sivatumma HTML code did changed also. I described everything.

Comment: Exactly what i'm looking for thank you! Just one more question - i need it to display the result for 1 lesson on page load as it is blank at the moment until i click on 2 lessons etc. Any ideas?

Comment: Nevermind i was being silly you just have to add a value to the answer form field :)

Comment: Hey guys! If you read through the original post again you'll notice i added the rest of the HTML form but now the calculation doesn't seem to be working??

Answer (score 0):

1. You use `$('.select')` while the elements have class name `option`,
2. You should use `change` event instead of `keyup`
3. you use `$('.cf_package_type')` while it's a `name`, not `class` attribute

http://jsfiddle.net/GuBPL/4/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".option").change(function(){
          var val1 = +$("[name=cf_package_type]").val();
          var val2 = +$("[name=cf_number]").val();
          $("#result").val(val1*val2);
    });
});
```